# Laravel error compact(): Undefined variable

Tags: laravel

i got error

`compact(): Undefined variable: 1`

in `{ return view('front.catepro',compact('category_products',$id_)); }`

but i all data correct in db and other route

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Products_model;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //$this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $products=Products_model::all();
        return view('front.home',compact('products'));
    }

    public function shop()
    {
        $products=Products_model::all();
        return view('front.shop',compact('products'));
    }

    public function showCates($id)
    {
        $category_products=Products_model::where('category_id',$id)->get();
        $id_=$id;
        return view('front.catepro',compact('category_products',$id_));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why using extra variable when you can directly send parameter like

```
public function showCates($id)
{
    $category_products=Products_model::where('category_id',$id)->get();
    return view('front.catepro',compact('category_products','id'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this

```
$category_products=Products_model::where('category_id',$id)->get();
$id=$id; //Remove underscore
return view('front.catepro',compact('category_products','id'));
```

Answer (score -1):

This will work

```
public function showCates($id)
{
    $category_products=Products_model::where('category_id',$id)->get();
    $id_=$id;
    return view('front.catepro',compact('category_products','id'));

}
```

But No need to assign **id** again in controller.Because you get it so just pass it my suggetion to you

```
public function showCates($id)
{
    $category_products=Products_model::where('category_id',$id)->get();
    return view('front.catepro',compact('category_products','id'));

}
```

its perfect